IF AND Formula excel
Current formula is:
=IF(VLOOKUP(B2,CPRS!A:AX,50,0)="D2C Exclusive","Yes","")
HOWEVER, I want to add to the above the below if the result is ""
=VLOOKUP(B2,CPRS!A:S,19,0) if it states BMG put BMG and if it doesnt state BMG put nothing
I hope that makes sense

I'm not sure how the two formulas go together but something like =LET(myLookup,VLOOKUP(B2,CPRS!A:S,19,0),IF(myLookup="BMG","BMG","")) maybe?

I will check that out thank you

The way I understood it, it would be:
=IF(VLOOKUP(B2,CPRS!A:AX,50,0)="D2C Exclusive", "Yes", IF(VLOOKUP(B2,CPRS!A:S,19,0)="BMG", "BMG", ""))

Thank you so much, you suggestion has worked perfectly.
